# Touch keypad buttons in calabash-android

Tags: calabash

Is there any way to tap on keypad button in calabash -android (like :1,2,3,4)

Note : Tap should be physical tap , as we got with "keyboard_enter_text" command in iOS

Answer (score 0):

For Android you can use keyboard_enter_text"1,2,3,4".
You have to have touched the field first, so that it is in focus.

Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: it seems not working for android :  NoMethodError: undefined method `keyboard_enter_text' for main:Object
 from (irb):6

Comment: What version of calabash-android are you using? I am on 5.0 pre2

Comment: 0.5.0 calabash-android version .But keyboard_enter_text is also pushing the value to text field .. i need it to tap on keypad button to enter the value in text field

Comment: Okay. Well in that case my suggestion won't help you. Why do you need it to tap on the keypad buttons? I imagine you could do touch field to bring up keypad, and then use some querye+touch to hit the keypbad buttons.. Have you tried that?

Answer (score -1):

Calabash doesn't support it but you can use adb to press keyboard keys

```
adb shell input text "what%syou%want%stype"
```

In ruby you can execute terminal commands in a couple of ways but I use backticks

```
`adb shell input text "what%syou%want%stype"`
```

See here for more info - http://krazyrobot.com/2014/02/calabash-android-enter-text-from-keyboard-using-adb/

EDIT: Not too sure on the cause of the downvote but here's a bit more info on my answer in case it makes any more sense to anyone.

The equivalent function of keyboard_enter_text for calabash-android has the same name.  It is in the TextHelpers module of calabash-android.  To use it, you have to

```
require 'calabash-android/text_helpers'
```

However the implementation of keyboard_enter_text seems to be different behind the scenes for android in as far as it sets the text value in the field to the whole word/phrase like it has been pasted in, rather than with individual keypresses like it does for ios.  As far as I know you can simulate the individual keypresses using adb commands if that is what you want.

I'm not sure why you would need to click on the keyboard buttons specifically, rather than just be happy that the text is in the field, as it is slower, but if you do for some reason then the adb commands should work.